# Is there a way to get from a DFS output to a BFS output?

Tags: python, list, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I have been struggling with the following problem: I have a DFS outputted list:
[0.2500000074505806,
0.6500000059604645,
0.15000000223517418,
0.45000000298023224,
0.45000000298023224,
0.8499999940395355,
0.15000000223517418]
and want to transform this to a BFS ordering without first creating a tree and then applying BFS. For reference, this is a complete binary graph with depth 2.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please don't add these thankful messages like `thanks in advance` etc. SO is a place where everyone helps each other, so we these type of phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general graphs, DFS doesn’t contain enough information to obtain the BFS output. But if you’re sure the graph is a complete binary tree on 7 nodes, and you ran DFS from the root and output is x1,x2,x3,…,x7, then the BFS output would be x1,x2,x5,x3,x4,x6,x7.

More generally, if you have the DFS output for a complete binary tree on n nodes, the permutation that gives the BFS output can be generated by the following algorithm:

```
k = 3   # number of levels in complete binary tree
n = 2**k   #so node labels are 1,2,...,n-1
L = list(range(1, n))

def toBFS(L):
    #input: a sequence of node labels, obtained by DFS on a complete binary tree
    #output: the sequence of node labels if BFS was performed
    #Q = a queue of all sublists to be processed
    #each sublist q has length 2^k-2
    #process each sublist by printing 1st, and n/2th element
    #and partitioning into two subsublists, both added to queue
    print(L[0])
    Q = []
    Q.append(L[1:len(L)])
    while len(Q) > 0:
        q = Q.pop(0)    #removes first element of Q
        if len(q) <= 2:
            for x in q:
                print(x)
        else:
            print(q[0])
            n = len(q)
            print(q[n//2])
            Q.append(q[1:n//2])
            Q.append(q[n//2+1:n])
        
toBFS(L)
```

Output:

```
1
2
5
3
4
6
7
```

The algorithm takes as input the DFS sequence, and prints the root node, then does the following for each sublist in the FIFO queue: prints the left child, then adds about half of the elements as a sublist to a queue, then prints the right child, then adds about half of the elements as a sublist to a queue.

Comment: Thank you ! What I am struggling with is an arbitrary complete binary tree on n nodes, Can we now turn this node list x1,.... , xn into a BFS output?

Comment: I've updated the answer for arbitrary n.

Answer (score 0):

When the tree is guaranteed to be a [perfect binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees), i.e. where the leaves of the tree are all on the bottom level, then you could use a pragmatic approach where you populate the levels of the level order traversal as separate lists, and then return the concatenation of those values:

```
def preorder_to_levelorder(seq):
    height = int(len(seq) ** 0.5)
    levels = [[] for _ in range(height+1)]
    it = iter(seq)
    
    def recur(depth):
        if depth > height:
            return
        try:
            val = next(it)
        except:
            return
        levels[depth].append(val)
        recur(depth + 1)
        recur(depth + 1)

    recur(0)
    return [val for level in levels for val in level]
```

Example perfect tree:

```
        4
      /   \
     2     6
    / \   / \
   1   3 5   7
```

Example run for that tree:

```
preorder = [4, 2, 1, 3, 6, 5, 7]
print(preorder_to_levelorder(preorder))  # [4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7]
```